# What is the best way to add a reply system on a message board im programming?

Tags: php, posting

I am currently coding a board, quite similar to a chan at this point in it's life but it wont end as such.  Anyways currently I have a basic system working boxes up top, type in than it posts down below.  Now to display the information (it is inserted into a mysql table) I perform a mysql query to pull out the information and than do a mysql_fetch_assoc, that goes into the while loop parameters and than I put in what I want to loop so the section is as follows.

```
$get_posts = mysql_query("SELECT `title`, `content`, `time`, `id`, `user` FROM `General - Off Topic` ORDER BY time DESC");
while($get_posts_thing = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_posts)) {
echo $get_posts_thing['title'];
echo $get_posts_thing['content'];
}
```

Thats basically what it looks like but it's in a div for styling.  Anyways I want to make a reply system where you click the reply button and a text box appears and you type in your reply and click post.  I want the post to appear under the post being replied to, styled in a div.  Since it's in a while loop I cant individually pick things out.  Any suggestions?
And sorry this is my first post and my first real php project so I don't know some things.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop, have a `<button onClick="reply(this);>`. Then in your JavaScript, define the `reply` function to take the button as its argument, and then work from there to put in the textbox etc.

Comment: Similarly outside of the while loop you can declare a variable that you can increment inside the while loop and use that to create an ID that you can work with in HTML/JS.

Comment: PHP outputs HTML/CSS/JavaScript.